# Unable to call LogoutSuccessHandler - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement a **Custom** Spring Security Logout Handler. My configurations are as below but the logout handler is never called.

I have a JSP where I call logout as :

```
<a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
```

In the application-security.xml, I have the following:

```
    <security:logout  invalidate-session="true"></security:logout>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="myCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"></security:logout>  


<beans:bean id="myCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"  class="com.inventory.security.MyCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"></beans:bean>
```

I have a Custom Logout handler too with the defination:

```
public class MyCustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends
SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

     @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess
          (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
          throws IOException, ServletException {
         System.out.println("Principal: "+authentication.getPrincipal());
         System.out.println("Logout Called: MyCustomLogoutSuccessHandler");

            super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
}
```

But this is never been called. Am I missing something?

If I change the j_spring_security_logout to logout and create my custom Controller for that URL , then in that case the code works for logout URL but how do I handle the Spring **Magic** Logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it isn't clear how you want to invoke your `myCustomLogoutSuccessHandler`, if you continue to use standard logout url (`j_spring_security_logout`), not your custom one - `logout`.

From other side what is the reason to have two `<security:logout>` ?

Won't it be enough to have this config:

```
<a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
....
<security:logout invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="myCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"></security:logout>
```

?

Explain your purpose, please

Comment: Looks like .. this answer solved my problem. Thanks a ton Artem.. I had the logout-url="/logout" which was goofing up.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing special work in custom logout handler...
since its a simple logout, so the following logout will work....>>>

**configuration**

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.html" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</security:http>
```

**html:**

```
<a style="margin-top: 4px;" href="/logout">log_out</a>
```

**for your information:**

```
Attribute : logout-url
Specifies the URL that will cause a logout. Spring Security will initialize a filter that responds to this particular URL. 
 Defaults to /j_spring_security_logout if unspecified.
```

if you are not specifing the attribute **logout-url** then it will default to **/j_spring_security_logout** it means you have to put **/j_spring_security_logout** in your html logout tags as

```
<a style="margin-top: 4px;" href="../j_spring_security_logout">log_out</a>
```

and if you are specifing the same attribute you have to put the same url in both config and html tags.like

**configuration:**

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.html" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</security:http>
```

**html:**

```
<a style="margin-top: 4px;" href="/logout">log_out</a>
```